# How to typecast an object in the java Stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I typecast an object inside the nested list's Object -:

```
C c = GenericScreenDataBean fieldObjx = this.expenseLineItemList.stream()
                .flatMap(a -> a.getSectionModel().getControls().stream())
                .filter(b -> b.getData() instanceof GenericScreenDataBean)
                .map(GenericScreenDataBean.class::cast)
                .filter(c->c.getFieldKey().equals("IncurredAmount")).findAny().orElse(null);
```

As the code mentioned above, Following is the descriptions-:

`List<expenseLineItemList>` is the master `List` for which I am invoking the stream API, then I am streaming on the `List<Controls>`.

Now, the data `getObject()` in the `Controls` class is the type of Object which I am trying to typecast here. As the map function `map(GenericScreenDataBean.class::cast)` will cast the `Controls.class`, I am getting the typecasting exception.

So, instead of typecasting the `Controls.class`, how can I typecast the `getControls().getObject()` and filter out the desired result?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `getData()` instead of `getObject()`, since use are using `getData()` in the filter step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are missing a `map` step:

```
C c = GenericScreenDataBean fieldObjx = this.expenseLineItemList.stream()
                .flatMap(a -> a.getSectionModel().getControls().stream())
                .filter(b -> b.getData() instanceof GenericScreenDataBean)
                .map(Controls::getData)
                .map(GenericScreenDataBean.class::cast)
                .filter(c->c.getFieldKey().equals("IncurredAmount")).findAny().orElse(null);
```

Or, if you want a single `map`, you can use a lambda expression instead of method references:

```
C c = GenericScreenDataBean fieldObjx = this.expenseLineItemList.stream()
                .flatMap(a -> a.getSectionModel().getControls().stream())
                .filter(b -> b.getData() instanceof GenericScreenDataBean)
                .map(c -> (GenericScreenDataBean) c.getData())
                .filter(c->c.getFieldKey().equals("IncurredAmount")).findAny().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Or `.map(Controls::getData) .filter(GenericScreenDataBean.class::isInstance) .map(GenericScreenDataBean.class::cast)`, or as a general pattern, if you’re going to `map` to the result of an expression anyway, do that first, instead of evaluating the same expression repeatedly…